# Change react.js(multi page app) with button element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

beginner with react.js. My goal is to switch pages in my app. I have made this component for export into another:

```
const component = ({ name, email, id }) => {
    return (
        <button href="secondContent.html" onclick="secondContent()" id="component">
            <div>
                header
            </div>
        </button>
    );
}
```

Function of this button was meant to be a switcher to second page (secondComponent).
I also have been trying to deal with html page to (actually) create that secondComponent file.
After trying to switch by this button for a few times, I could not get a result which I wanted.

If annyone can brief me with a proper way to solowe this problem and sugest me a better solution, pls help.
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways this can be achieved however for a simple sitatuion like this, you could do something like:

```
const component = ({name, email, id}) => {

   const gotoSecondContent = () => {
      window.location = "secondContent.html";
   }       

   return (
    <button onclick={ gotoSecondContent } id="component">
      <div>header</div>
    </button>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the react-router-dom documentation. I think you will find all you need there !

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy